# Ionic 2 vs Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, ionic2

I have found a lot of articles (and forms) about Ionic vs Xamarin but they always talk about Ionic 1 or Xamarin when it was still paid for (so before march 2016 when it was acquired by Microsoft).

I have to research Ionic 2 vs (current) Xamarin and I know that both technologies have made huge advancements. Can anyone help me on my way with some sources or is it still too early to ask this question?

Comment: These kind of questions can't be asked here, please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be aware of the sites rules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Xamarin**: With one year of experience, I have realise it is really flexible IDE to use. The amazing part about Xamarin is you have 2 option, i) go native ii) go cross platform, this make it open on what kind usage you prefer and how you want to go about.

OS Support/Deployment to: Windows, iOS, Android, Mac

Languages Used: XML, C#

**Ionic**: especially Ionic-2, It amazing for all HTML, CSS, and JS users to build application for web, mobile applications. I haven't seen its deployment for windows phone(if it is, then i am not sure) With Ionic, forget all your MVVM structured coding. But the new implementation of version-2 parallel with angular-2(typescript) it might make it possible to implement.

OS Support/Deployment to: iOS, Android, Web(HTML/CSS)

languages Used: HTML, CSS, Angular-2

**Star Rating**
**Xamarin** - Mobile and PC Dev - 4/5 stars on usage of IDE and deployment. There are immediate help available upon stuck through Xamarin Forums. Documentation is little vague.

**Ionic-2** - Mobile and Web Dev - 3/5 stars on usable and compatibility. Its hard to find some answers to specific question, rest ionic docs are great at documentation and implementation.

Hope this helps. PS: This is completely my own view as i have used both of this tools personally. Comments are welcomed.

Comment: since you used both, how do you compare the performance, and how easily is it to deploy the apps using both platforms?

Comment: @HusseinSalman Deployment is really easy on both the platforms. It is as simple as clicking a button. However, Ionic has a auto-increment the version so that when deploying it is not so painful to increase the number. Whereas for Xamarin, you need to change manually. But I still prefer Xamarin and the manual increment. As we have the complete control over the version. What if the increment goes wrong! What if we need specific number! And all! On Deployment I will say Xamarin still wins the race compared to Ionic. Though both get 3.5/5.

Comment: Great answer!
So Xamarin only supports mobile apps, while Ionic also supports web apps.

Comment: @CristiPotlog Yes. However please take note, the answer was written and not updated since Feb'17. I would recommend having some extra reading before making a decision.